# Why the browser is unable to find my views and how to resolve this issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project. I need help with an unhandled exception. I got my error view pages and error controller. Could somebody tell me why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Error' was not found. The following locations were searched:
> /Views/Error/Error.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
> /Pages/Shared/Error.cshtml
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable<string> originalLocations)

This is my `ErrorController`:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using ArtGallery.Web.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NuGet.Protocol.Plugins;

namespace ArtGallery.Web.Controllers
{
    public class ErrorController : BaseController
    {
        [Route("/Error/Error")]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return this.View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? this.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }

        [Route("/Error/404")]
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error404()
        {
            var errorModel = new ErrorViewModel
            { 
                  StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound,
                  RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? this.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier,
            };

            return View(errorModel);
        }

        [Route("/Error/500")]
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error500()
        {
            var errorModel = new ErrorViewModel
            {
                StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? this.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier,
            };

            return View(errorModel);
        }
    }
}
```

I got three Error Views I try to pull Error 404 and Error 500 in the Browsers, all of them including my Error View gives me the same error.

Error View

```
@model ErrorViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="error-page">
        <div class="error-content text">
            <h1 class="text-danger" style="color: ffea00">Oops, Error!</h1>
            <p class="text-danger">Something went wrong while processing your request.</p>
        </div>
        <strong>Status code:</strong> <code>Model.StatusCode</code>
        @if (Model.ShowRequestId)
            {
                <p>
                    <strong>Request ID:</strong> <code>@Model.RequestId</code>
                </p>
            } 
    </div>
</div>
```

Error404 View

```
@using ArtGallery.Common
@model ArtGallery.Web.ViewModels.ErrorViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "404";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="error-page">
        <div class="error-content image">
            <img src="@GlobalConstants.Images.Error404" class="img-thumbnail" />
        </div>
        <div class="error-content text">
            <h1 class="text-danger" style="color: darkblue">Oops!</h1>
            <h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
            <span>We are sorry, the page you are looking is not found or temporarlly unavailable. Please go back to Home Page. Thank you for your undestanding!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-primary">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/">GO HOME PAGE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Error500 View

```
@using ArtGallery.Common
@model ArtGallery.Web.ViewModels.ErrorViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "500";
 }

<div class="container">
    <div class="error-page">
        <div class="error-content image">
            <img src="@GlobalConstants.Images.Error500" class="img-thumbnail" />
        </div>
        <div class="error-content text">
            <h1 class="text-danger" style="color: darkblue">Oops!</h1>
            <h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
            <span>We will work on fixing that right away. Meanwhile, please go back to Home Page. Thank you for your undestanding!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-primary">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/">GO HOME PAGE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Browser is telling me that it could not find my Error Views but they are there I have them. Not sure why the Browser could not find my Error Views.

[Views Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0ytc.png)

Comment: Error views must be in /Views/Error/ or /Pages/Shared/ or /Views/Shared/

Comment: /Views/Error/Error.cshtml /Views/Shared/Error.cshtml /Pages/Shared/Error.cshtml, check your project folder, are these files present?

Comment: Did you put you Error400.cshtml in your Views in your Web folder?

Comment: Can you share the structure of your web folder about you views?

Comment: My latest [Views Structure][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0ytc.png You cab check it out here.

Answer (score 0):

I do your code again, but I don't meet the problem as yours.

Shown as below：

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I already fixed it. It is working.